# How to save has_many :through self-referencial association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've set up a self-referencial association using has_many :through, basically as described on this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association.

Some "activities" act kinda like "articles" and have an associated set of other activities, hence the naming of the join table. It is a little confusing... I know.

I am having a tough time getting things to save right. Here is what I've got...

**activity.rb**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :article_activities
  has_many :activities, :through => :article_activities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :activities
end
```

**article_activity.rb**

```
class ArticleActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article_id, :activity_id
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :article, :class_name => "Activity"
end
```

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.is_article = true
    @user_activities = current_user.activities
  end

  def create
    @activity = Activity.new params[:activity]
    @activity.is_article = true
    @activity.user = current_user

    if @activity.save
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Article created!"
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

**new.html.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @activity, :url => articles_path do |f|
  / Other fields omitted for clarity
  = f.association :activities, :collection => @user_activities
```

So, upon submitting the form, `@activity` in the `create` action has the expected `@activity.activities`. However, upon saving `@activity` and reloading the record,  `@activity.activities` is empty.

Any ideas how to save the associations?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out. I had to add a :foreign_key for "article" to the models...

```
class ArticleActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :article_id, :activity_id
  belongs_to :activity
  belongs_to :article, :class_name => "Activity", :foreign_key => "article_id"
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :article_activities, :foreign_key => "article_id"
  has_many :activities, :through => :article_activities 
end
```